# Resizing the window results in bitmaps being overwritten

Tags: c++, bitmap, resize, window, gdi

I've been messing around with bitmaps and rendering in Visual C++ and hit a weird problem.

I'm trying to get the drawing area to resize when the user resizes the window. Right now, not only does enlarging the window not enlarge the visible drawing area (white borders appear outside of where the original window bounds were), but changing the window size seems to be messing with my bitmaps.

Here's what the game looks like on start-up:

[image]

After changing the width or height of the window, the purple character has now been replace by the orange one.

[image]

And finally, all three become blue.

[image]

If I keep going, all the characters will be overwritten by the green grass background bitmap.

[image]

It seems to happen in the reverse order that the bitmaps are rendered in.  Adding a second row of characters confirmed it's a not a problem in the rendering code - the actual bitmaps in memory are getting changed somehow.  Removing the resize code causes the bitmap error to stop repro-ing.

It's almost certainly a mistake in my resize code, when I try to reinitialize the device contexts, but I'm not sure what it is.

Here's the relevant set-up code:

```
HBITMAP player_blue = (HBITMAP) LoadImage (NULL, L"Images/test_player_blue.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
HBITMAP player_orange = (HBITMAP) LoadImage (NULL, L"Images/test_player_orange.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
HBITMAP player_purple = (HBITMAP) LoadImage (NULL, L"Images/test_player_purple.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
HBITMAP background_bitmap = (HBITMAP) LoadImage (NULL, L"Images/test_background.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

  HDC hdc = GetDC (Window);
  HDC hdc_temp = CreateCompatibleDC (hdc);
  HBITMAP bitmap_buffer = CreateCompatibleBitmap (hdc, resize.screen_width, resize.screen_height);
  SelectObject (hdc, bitmap_buffer);
```

The main loop from wWinMain():

```
  while (!Exit)
    {
    while (PeekMessage (&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
      {
      DispatchMessage(&msg);
      }
    Render ();
    }
```

The callback function where the resizing is done:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
  {
  switch (message)
    {
    case WM_SIZE:

      RECT window_rect;
      if (GetWindowRect (Window, &window_rect))
        {
        hdc = GetDC (Window);
        hdc_temp = CreateCompatibleDC (hdc);
        bitmap_buffer = CreateCompatibleBitmap (hdc, resize.screen_width, resize.screen_height);
        SelectObject (hdc, bitmap_buffer);

        screen_width = window_rect.right - window_rect.left;
        screen_height = window_rect.bottom - window_rect.top;
        }
      break;

    default:
      return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
  return 0;
  }
```

The actual rendering via BitBlt():

```
void Render ()
  {
  SelectObject (hdc_temp, background_bitmap);
  BitBlt (hdc, 0, 0, 800, 600, hdc_temp, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

  SelectObject (hdc_temp, player_blue);
  BitBlt (hdc, 0, 0, 126, 126, hdc_temp, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
  SelectObject (hdc_temp, player_orange);
  BitBlt (hdc, 126, 0, 126, 126, hdc_temp, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
  SelectObject (hdc_temp, player_purple);
  BitBlt (hdc, 252, 0, 126, 126, hdc_temp, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
  }
```

Comment: It's been a long time since I used the Windows API, but don't you need to restore the original handle to the `hdc_temp`? eg: `Render() { HGDIOBJ h = SelectObject (hdc_temp, background_bitmap); /*existing code*/ SelectObject(hdc_temp, h); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ken commented, you are leaking precious GDI resources. A few more resizes and your window might go all black :)

Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatibledc :

`When you no longer need the memory DC, call the DeleteDC function.` You probably don't need to create that DC on every resize.

Same goes for `CreateCompatibleBitmap`.

Comment: Thanks - it looks like that was the culprit.  Any insight on how to properly resize the drawing area?

Comment: @NightmareGames - it depends on what you want to do: just resize the background, or scale your game pieces? In any way, while handling the `WM_SIZE` message you only need to get the new size (and may be prepare the DC) as you already do. Make sure that when you assign a new GDI resource to an existing handle, you clean the previous content first. Also note that you can't delete the resource that is currently selected into any DC, so the good practice is (as Ken commented) to save previously selected object on exit from your `Render()`. Another alternative is to use `SaveDC()` and `RestoreDC()`